# Type error on React Route component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to use the route Route component but it's throwing the following error:

> [ts] Type '{ path: "/:shortname"; component: typeof FirstComponent; }'
>   is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>
>   & Rea...'.

Here's my route config:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Link to='/customer'></Link>
    <Route path='/:shortname' component={FirstComponent} />
</Router>
```

These are the versions I'm using:

```
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.5"
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
```

Comment: your code looks right, Im using typescript as well, but im not getting this error.

Comment: Could you upload the code for your `FirstComponent` component? It's clear that the error is the interface between react-router and that component, so we may need to see that code to determine the true root cause.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, the problem is that `<Router/>` element only accepts **single** child. While your children for Router is an array of Link & Route.

Try wrap your Link and Routes with div or even fancier [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) (after react 16.2+)

```
<Router>
  <React.Fragment>
    <Link to='/customer'></Link>
    <Route path='/:shortname' component={FirstComponent} />
  </React.Fragment>
</Router>
```